# Pass data from closure function into Segue variable

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, closures

I am rather new to Swift, and especially the use of Closures in the framework. I have the following class function that returns a document from Firestore and builds a model from the document returned. I am able to pass in a closure to allow me to receive the model:

```
func getUpdatedModel(callback: @escaping (AccountModel?)->Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ref = db.collection("collectionName").document(self.documentId!)
 
    ref.getDocument { (document, error) in
                guard let document = document, document.exists else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                    return
                   // callback(nil,nil)
                }
                let dataDescription = document.data()
 
      let model = AccountModel.init(dataDescription!, userId: "test")

      callback(model)
            }
    }
```

I have a method to load a Segue, where I'm trying to get the result from this closure to be passed into the Segue's variable for further logic:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        self.accountModel?.getUpdatedModel() { model in
            if let error = error {
                return
            }
            
            let d = model
        }
 
        if let vc = segue.destination as? AnotherViewController {
            vc.account = d // model returned above
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to store the result of the value retrieved in the closure to be passed into my `vc.account` variable for the `AnotherViewController`. I also get into further troubles if I try to first call my `self.accountModel?.getUpdatedModel()` method and then put the `if let vc = ...` logic inside it. I know the async/await code being called from Firestore is causing code to run before other code in this block, but I can't seem to figure out the proper closure technique to reach my goal.

The overall goal here is to first reach out and grab this Firestore document, then build the model from its contents, then return that model to then be passed into the ViewController called in my Segue. I may not even need to use a closure for all I know. Obviously I'm a bit lost here and would appreciate any help.

Comment: have you tried to call the "if let vc = segue.destination as? AnotherViewController {" in the closure block ?, i mean direct after the " let d = model" ...?

Comment: What are you doing with it after you get a model returned by the 'getUpdatedModel' guy?

Comment: I can only assume that having this in the segue call is messing something up here? Even if I comment out the entire `vc` logic that should direct the screen to show, the screen still loads (since I assume it is set in Storyboard) and crashes due to the model not built. Is this "a thing" in Swift?

Comment: @Osman so per my above comment, when I place the `if let vc...` into the closure it does nothing.
@ElTomato I can only assign the variable inside the closure. How can I return the variable to be used outside of the closure to be used later down in the code?

Comment: The Firestore related `ref.getDocument` may be async which is messing this flow up somehow?

Comment: @ManWithBear any ideas?

Comment: So you are calling the getUpdatedModel guy only when you switch the view controller to AnotherViewController?  If that's the case, it doesn't sound like a good plot.